# Filter table data depending of a url id in vueJS

Tags: javascript, json, filter, html-table, vue.js

I want to get data from a JSON API depending of the id in the url page.
First I have the code of my table that have link depending of a url id that go to the second table template:

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tr style="text-align:left;" v-for="data in metadata">
        <td>{{data.id}}</td>
        <td><router-link :to="{ name: 'mixtapesDetails', params{id : data.id}}">
            {{data.title}}
        </router-link></td>
        <td><router-link :to="{ name: 'mixtapesDetails', params{id : data.id}}">
            {{data.artist}}
        </router-link></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There is my second table where I only want to display my data depending of the ID:

```
    <div style="margin-left:400px;">
        <div>{{$route.params.id}}</div>
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="text-align:left;" v-for="data in metadata">
                <td>{{data.id}}</td>
                <td>{{data.title}}</td>
                <td>{{data.artist}}</td> 
                <td>{{data.cover}}</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Then I have my Js function to get all my data :

```
export default {
  data(){
    return {
        metadata: null
    }
  },
  methods:{
    httpGet(theUrl){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false); // true for asynchronous request
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    console.log(JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText));
    return JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.metadata = this.httpGet("urltooJsondata");
  }
}
```

And then I have my routes in JS :

```
export default new VueRouter({
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/mixtapeList',
        name: 'mixtapeList',
        component: mixtapeList
      },
    {
        path: '/mixtapesDetails/:id',
        name: 'mixtapesDetails',
        component: mixtapesDetails
    }
    ]
  })
```

The objective is that when I click on a router-link it goes to a single page with a url like this /mixtapesdetails/id, and I want that the the data displayed on that page are the data which correspond to the url id.

I really need help and I don't find the solution on web.

Answer (score 0):

I think that for this purposes is there `$route.params` object. So if you have route like this,

```
{
  path: '/mixtapesDetails/:anything',
  name: 'mixtapesDetails',
  component: mixtapesDetails
}
```

in `mixtapesDetails` component implementation you can access `:anything` path segment value with `$route.params.anything`.

Comment: Yes I edited that, i forgot to put my second table where i want to display my data. The problem is that I don't know how to get the other values of my table depending of my ID.

Comment: But these additional data have nothing to do routing... Are you using Vuex?

Comment: I use VueJS in a WebPack Environment. Maybe i make the question more complex adding the routing part but i thought this part was necessary to understand the question.

Comment: It seems you have bad architecture. Are you trying to store JSON obtained from ajax call in route metadata?

Comment: I get my Json data in the metadata variable and then i display them in an html table helped with a for loop. This part is okay it correspond to my first table. The second table is here to get only the data of my JSON API corresponding to one ID, this one is in the url and i don't know how to do that.

Comment: Both tables are in one component?

Comment: No they are in two different component.

Comment: I though that... What you need is shared store. Store you can access from different components in uniform way.

Comment: Okay and if the components are on the same page do you know how i can do this easier ?

Comment: Load JSON to `data` structure in Vue instance itself, and send it to components through props.

Comment: How can i send it to components through props exactly. My problem is that i don't know how to filter the data only to get the data linked to the ID.